# When i want to solve the leetcode.225 in pure c, there's something wrong

Tags: c, data-structures, stack, queue

'''
With the help of the answer, I modified the code, such as the return type and function parameter settings. Thank you all here, but I still don't understand why my code still reports such an error. I checked a lot of information and felt that there was nothing wrong with the code in the enqueue function. What is going wrong? thank you very much !
'''

```
typedef struct {
    int val;
    struct QNode* next;
}QNode;

typedef struct {
    struct QNode *rear;
    struct QNode *front; 
}Queue;

typedef struct {
    struct Queue *q1;
    struct Queue *q2;
}MyStack;


Queue* qcreate(void){
    Queue* q = malloc(sizeof(Queue));

    q->front = NULL;
    q->rear = NULL;
    return q;
}

bool qisempty(Queue* q){
    return (q->rear == NULL);
}

void enqueue(Queue *q, int x){
    QNode *qn = malloc(sizeof(QNode));
    qn->val = x;
    qn->next = NULL;

    if(q->front==NULL){
        q->front = q->rear = qn; // line 35
    }
    else{
        q->rear->next = qn; // line 38
        q->rear = qn;
    }
}

int dequeue(Queue* q){
    QNode *pt;
    int n = q->front->val;
    pt = q->front;
    
    q->front = q->front->next;
    
    free(pt);
    return(n);
}

void freeq(Queue* q){
    while(!qisempty(q)){
        dequeue(q);
    }
    q->front = q->rear = NULL
    free(q);
}

/** Initialize your data structure here. */

MyStack* myStackCreate() {
    MyStack* st = (MyStack*)malloc(sizeof(MyStack));

    st->q1 = qcreate();
    st->q2 = qcreate();
    return st;
}

/** Push element x onto stack. */
void myStackPush(MyStack* obj, int x) {
    int m;
    while(!qisempty(obj->q1)){
        m = dequeue(obj->q1);
        enqueue(obj->q2, m);
    }
    enqueue(obj->q1, x);
    while(!qisempty(obj->q2)){
        m = dequeue(obj->q2);
        enqueue(obj->q1, m);
    }
}

/** Removes the element on top of the stack and returns that element. */
int myStackPop(MyStack* obj) {
    int m;
    m = dequeue(obj->q1);
    return m;
}

/** Get the top element. */
int myStackTop(MyStack* obj) {
    return obj->q1->front->val;
}

/** Returns whether the stack is empty. */
bool myStackEmpty(MyStack* obj) {
    return qisempty(obj->q1);
}

void myStackFree(MyStack* obj) {
    freeq(obj->q1);
    freeq(obj->q2);
}

/**
 * Your MyStack struct will be instantiated and called as such:
 * MyStack* obj = myStackCreate();
 * myStackPush(obj, x);
 
 * int param_2 = myStackPop(obj);
 
 * int param_3 = myStackTop(obj);
 
 * bool param_4 = myStackEmpty(obj);
 
 * myStackFree(obj);
*/`enter code here`
```

solution.c: In function ‘enqueue’

Line 35: Char 28: warning: assignment to ‘struct QNode *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘QNode *’ {aka ‘struct  *’} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
q->front = q->rear = qn;
^

Line 38: Char 16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct QNode’
q->rear->next = qn;
^~

Comment: The error indicates that you're calling `qisempty()` with an uninitialized pointer. You'll need to use a stack trace in the debugger to see which call is causing that, and then figure out why the variable isn't initialized.

Comment: Can you give us the `main` function so we can see how you use the stack?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
void qinit(){
```

and you call it like:

```
qinit(st->q1);
qinit(st->q2);
```

Apparently, you expect the function to initialize `st->q1` and `st->q2` but it doesn't. You probably wanted:

```
void qinit(){
    ....
    return MALLOCED_AND_INITIALIZED_QUEUE_POINTER;
}

st->q1 = qinit();
st->q2 = qinit();
```

**So why didn't you get a compiler warning/error ?**

Well, `void qinit()` means a function that takes an **unspecified** number of parameters so you don't get a warning for `qinit(st->q1);`.

Had you used: `void qinit(void)` the compiler would have screamed at you.

Lesson: Never use an empty parameter list in a function. Use `void` if it takes no parameter.

Besides that:

Here is a bug that needs to be fixed too.

Here:

```
void freeq(struct Queue* q){
    while(!qisempty(q)){
        dequeue(q);
    }
    free(q->front);   // q-> front is NULL due to the while above
                      // so this does nothing

    free(q->rear);    // q->rear is pointing to an already free'ed object
                      // so this is an error
}
```

In other words - both `free` should be deleted.

And here:

```
int dequeue(struct Queue* q){
    struct QNode *pt;
    int n = q->front->val;
    pt = q->front;
    
    q->front = q->front->next;
    q->count--;
    free(pt);
    return(n);
}
```

you are missing an update of `q->rear`. Like:

```
    if (q->front == NULL) q->rear = NULL;
    return(n);
```

And a comment regarding the design:

Why do you push at the end of the queue and pop from the front?

That is how a FIFO works.

For a stack you would normally do both push and pop in the same way. That will really simplify your code. Further, it will perform a lot better.

If you always push and pop from the front you can

1. Delete `q2` in `MyStack`
2. Delete `rear` in `struct Queue`

and consequently delete all code that operates on those.

Comment: thanks a lot !   [link]https://leetcode.com/problems/implement-stack-using-queues/

Comment: [link]https://leetcode.com/problems/implement-stack-using-queues/   i have no idea about the main(), sorry. Thanks for your suggestion, I have benefited a lot from it and it is very useful for me. I made some improvements, such as the init function, the return type was changed to struct Queue*, and the parameter was struct Queue* q, but my code still didn't run through, and the error was still the same. My foundation is a bit poor, this part of the content is a bit convoluted for me, I am trying to learn the basics. If you have time, I still hope to give some pointers. thanks